# C# Scope of array

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and having trouble understanding the scope of variables. I've declared an array at the beginning of the class:

```
namespace TextProcessing
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static string[] ForewordArray;
```

Then in Main, I initialize and fill the array:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    //snip - XML source is opened - snip
                    foreword = XMLnav.SelectSingleNode("//iso:foreword", NSmgr);
                    forewordText = foreword.InnerXml;
                    ForewordTextP = (forewordText.Length - forewordText.Replace("<p", string.Empty).Length) / 2 + 1;
                    CurrFPos = 1;
                    LastFPos = 1;
                    string[] ForewordArray = new string[ForewordTextP];
                    for (var z = 0; z <= ForewordTextP - 1; z++)
                    {
                        LastFPos = CurrFPos;
                        if (z < ForewordTextP - 1)
                        {
                            CurrFPos = Strings.InStr(LastFPos, forewordText, "<p");
                            if (LastFPos > 1)
                            {
                                ForewordArray[z] = Strings.Left(Strings.Mid(forewordText, LastFPos - 1), CurrFPos - LastFPos - 1);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ForewordArray[z] = Strings.Left(Strings.Mid(forewordText, LastFPos), CurrFPos - LastFPos - 1);
                            }
                            CurrFPos = CurrFPos + 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CurrFPos = Strings.InStr(LastFPos, forewordText, "p>");
                            ForewordArray[z] = Strings.Left(Strings.Mid(forewordText, LastFPos-1), CurrFPos - LastFPos + 3);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

After some other text processing, when execution returns to the array (still in Main!), it's null:

```
                    foreach (var bkmkStart in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
                    {
                        if (bkmkStart.Name == "ForewordText")
                        {
                            forewordbkmkParent = bkmkStart.Parent;
                            for (var y = 0; y <= ForewordArray.Length - 1; y++)
                            {
                                var TextProcessP = new Para2XML(ForewordArray[y]);
                                forewordbkmkParent.InsertBeforeSelf(TextProcessP.PReturn);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Is this happening because I initialize the array inside a Try loop?
I've read dozens of pages about variable scope in C# and I'm still not getting it. Thanks for any reading suggestions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Do not split up the code and leave maybe important code out.

Comment: Side note: variable names and field names should begin in lowercase, so they don't get confused with class names, method names or property names, which start in uppercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are declaring a new local array inside Main and this is getting initialized with data.  It looks like the second block of code is then accessing the class level array, which was never initialized.

In Main, the following line is declaring a new string array called ForewordArray because you start this line with the type.

```
string[] ForewordArray = new string[ForewordTextP];
```

In order to initialize the array you declared up at the top of the class, this should be as follows:

```
ForewordArray = new string[ForewordTextP];
```

Answer (score 1):

Scope is actually pretty simple. If a class contains a variable, anything within that class sees it. However, anything outside that class/block cannot access that variable.

It's like a hierarchy of dropdowns. Click on a dropdown, and you see everything it contains. If it contains other dropdowns, click on those, and you see what they contain. Each dropdown only knows about the stuff it contains. This means that the dropdown which contains everything (or, in other words, within which everything is nested) can see everything.

There is a complication when variables are named the same way. If one class contains a variable, and a class within it contains another variable with the same name, the class inside will override the variable's name, because it is more precise in context.

Writing `string[] ForewordArray = new ...` declares a new array variable. So the containing class `Program`'s `ForewordArray` is getting overridden by the child class' `ForewordArray`. The notation `string[]` creates a new variable of type string array. To initialize the variable instead, just use the variable name `ForewordArray`.